# Как найти наименьший множитель в python?

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())

    i = 1
    j = 1

    for i in range(2, 10000):
        if i != 0:
            if a / i == 0 and b / i == 0:
                print(i)
                break

    for j in range(2, 10000):
        if j / a == 0 and j / b == 0:
            print(j)
            break
```

мне нужно найти наибольшее натуральное число, на которое `a` и `b` делится без остатка и наименьшее натуральное число, которое делится на `a` и `b` без остатка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наибольший общий делитель:

```
def bcs(a, b):
    while a!= 0 and b!= 0:
        if a>b:
            a%=b
        else:
            b%=a
    print(a+b)
```

Наименьшее общее кратное:

```
def lcm(a, b):
    m = a * b
    while a != 0 and b != 0:
        if a > b:
            a %= b
        else:
            b %= a
    print(m // (a + b))
```